# NullException when setting OnRatingBarChangeListener in Android

Tags: android

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to set a listener on my rating bar
My ratingBar is inside a scrollView and above, outside this view there's a videoView wich plays a video.
My code:

```
final RatingBar videoRating=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBarNews);
videoRating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {          
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar rBar, float fRating, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.i("rate_news", fRating);

        }
    });
```

The exception is thrown at:

```
setOnRatingBarChangeListener
```

Is this because it's inside a scrollView, I tried a lot but with no success.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: whether the id is currect...... If s clean and rebuild the project and then run it.. hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this code runs after your call to `setContentView()`. If you do it before that, findViewById will return null. If this is already after the call to `setContentView`, make sure your layout specified in that call actually contains the view with that id.

Comment: Omg...I chose the wrong id, that one was from another layout, hence the confusion :| Thank you for making me thorough check :)